# Nodemon not refreshing with Vite Express when using routing

Tags: express, vite

I am building a simple Express app. I have used Vite with React, but it seems to not handle SSR. So I have installed Vite Express. HMR is working in the sample app installed with Vite Express. After typing npm run dev, my app is loading in the browser, but nodemon only restarts if there are changes in /server/main.js, and not my .ejs files. Thus, no HMR in the browser either.

The differences between that app and mine is my /server/main.js uses routing (with EJS templating). The former uses an index.html in the root, which runs a script module /client/main.js. That module contains the html page. No routing, just a single page.

How do I get the HMR working with routing?

/src/server/main.js:

```
import express from "express";
import ViteExpress from "vite-express";

const app = express();

app.use(ViteExpress.static())

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'src/client/views'); 

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
  res.render('home', {name: 'Home'});
})

ViteExpress.listen(app, 3000, () =>
  console.log("Server is listening on port 3000..."),
);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vite-starter",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server/main.js -w src",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node src/server/main.js",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "vite-express": "*"
  }
}
```

I've verified I have the package.json script for nodemon watching the correct directory. It didn't change anything.

I've tried to put files in similar directories as the default app. It didn't change anything.